# On iPhone when I take vertical picture my vue component is not works correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, exif

I have problems displaying recently uploaded photos to a form. If the image was made by phone, it may have an exif property, but the browser does not handle this property, it turns out that the picture can be flipped over or on the side.

[upside down picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7DdN.png)

I solved this problem with the exif-js library. Having written (having stolen on some website) a component and having spent a lot of time, I achieved that during loading and processing, the picture turns in the right direction.

[right side picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhk1w.png)

But during the test, we found out that on iPhones, if you download not from photos, but take photos vertically manually, then the picture generally goes beyond the div to the lower left corner.

[iphone incorrectly image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ3a1.png)

After that all other photos are also displayed incorrectly. On android device all is fine.

In this img-tag: src changes dynamicly and I need 'transform' dynamicly too, so I need to use updated() method. I know this is bad code, but...

**Usage**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 edit-activity-images">
            <auto-rotate><img class="edit-activity-images-inner" alt="activity"                                                 
          :src="getUploadedImageBackground()||staticFile('images/img-place-holder.png')"
                                        ></auto-rotate>
```

**Style**

```
 edit-activity-images-inner{
     object-fit: cover;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

**Component**

```
<template>
    <div class="holder">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
 </template>

<script>
    import imagesLoaded from 'imagesloaded'
    import EXIF from 'exif-js'

    const rotateAngles = [
        {},
        {y: 0, z: 0},
        {y: 180, z: 0},
        {y: 0, z: 180},
        {y: 180, z: 180},
        {y: 180, z: -90},
        {y: 0, z: -90},
        {y: 180, z: 90},
        {y: 0, z: 90}
    ];

function getOrientation(el) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        imagesLoaded(el, function () {
            EXIF.getData(el, function () {
                const orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, 'Orientation');
                resolve(orientation);
            })
        })
    })
}

function getRotationAngle(newOrientation, oldOrientation) {
    const y = rotateAngles[newOrientation].y - rotateAngles[oldOrientation].y;
    let z = rotateAngles[newOrientation].z - rotateAngles[oldOrientation].z;
    if (y)
        z = z * -1;
    return { y, z }
}

const recently_added = {};
const havent_exif = {};

export default {
    name: "AutoRotate",
    updated() {
        const slot = this.$slots.default[0];
        if (slot.tag !== 'img') {
            console.error('Warning: slot should be an img tag.');
            return;
        }
        const holder = this.$el;
        const img = holder.childNodes[0];

        img.exifdata = undefined;
        if (recently_added[img.src]) {
            img.style['transform'] = recently_added[img.src];
            return
        } else if (havent_exif[img.src]) {
            img.style['transform'] = "translate(0px, 0px) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg)";
            return;
        }
        getOrientation(img).then(function (currentOrientation) {
            if (currentOrientation !== undefined) {
                const angle = getRotationAngle(1, currentOrientation);
                const transform = `rotateY(${angle.y}deg) rotateZ(${angle.z}deg)`;
                let translate = '';
                if (angle.z % 180 !== 0) {
                    const height = img.clientHeight;
                    const width = img.clientWidth;
                    translate = `translate(${(height - width) / 2}px, ${(width - height) / 2}px)`;
                    holder.style['width'] = `${height}px`;
                    holder.style['height'] = `${width}px`;
                }
                img.style['vertical-align'] = 'bottom';
                img.style['transform'] = translate + ' ' + transform;
                recently_added[img.src] = translate + ' ' + transform;
            } else {
                havent_exif[img.src] = true;
                if (!recently_added[img.src]) {
                    img.style['transform'] = "translate(0px, 0px) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg)";
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

```
<style scoped>
     .holder {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
 </style>
```

Well, hope someone can help me and write what can I do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I removed this part of code, because it works incorrect. And it's done...

```
if (angle.z % 180 !== 0) {
         const height = img.clientHeight;
         const width = img.clientWidth;
         translate = `translate(${(height - width) / 2}px, ${(width - height) / 2}px)`;
         holder.style['width'] = `${height}px`;
         holder.style['height'] = `${width}px`;
}
```